# How to implement sign in with Google in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to implement a sign in with google feature on a website.
The problem is that I can't find a library for Angular (11), for example [React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) has one.
Even if there isn't a library for angular, I can't find one for typescript, any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use OAuth to handle login with google, the following article goes into futher detail and shows a working example with vanillaJS:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: Is there typescript support for this library?

Comment: of course, I'm not sure there are type definitions however